# Using an ObservableCollection in a service

Tags: wpf, coding-style, event-handling, observablecollection

I have a few projects. One of the projects will be deployed as a Windows Service. An other project is a WPF application. There are a few other applications managing some data (of external hardware or the database). The data-lists are almost all `ObservableCollection`'s.

I've read around a bit and it seems like `ObservableCollection` is only really ment for the UI layer (the WPF application, in my case). Is that correct? Would I be better of using events (`PropertyChanged`) in the service/datamanager layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a service, usually all objects should only live as long as it takes to process the current request, correct? So, normally you wouldn't need change notification at all in the service layer, since the service would perform all changes to the model itself. For the next request, the required objects would be read again from the backing store.

Comment: Well, say 2 user interfaces can make use of the same Service (through a webconnection to that computer). One of the UI's has a list of Users open. The other UI navigates through the UI to add a User. He fills in the information and presses "Save". Currently, it's being added to the database and the `ObservableCollection` of Users is being updated. That would result in the other UI being updated as well. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In that case, the service needs to be able to push data to the client, even if there is no request. Normally, I'd just have the clients poll for updates of the user list in regular intervals, except in a peer to peer situation, where the clients are servers themselves. Anyway, since service and UI run on different computers, and events require live object references, this wouldn't work out of the box anyway.

Comment: Allright, that sounds fair enough! I have one question left though. I do use `ObservableCollection` in my service, to interact between classes (not being the UI). It's all in the same layer/setting, but I still get an error regarding threads. More information can be found in the seperate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211346/threading-in-a-windows-service . But in short: Can I use `ObservableCollection` in my service to check between classes, or is `RaiseProperty` eventing preferred?

Comment: Please see my answer to the other question... that would depend on how the hardware triggers the changes, and wether it is possible (and makes sense) to have all that running on one thread.